# How to install Petite Chez Scheme on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scheme, chez-scheme

> How to install Petite Chez Scheme on Ubuntu?

I run Ubuntu 15.10 and try to install pcsv8.4-a6le.tar.gz (non-threaded, 64 bit) for Linux.

After having unpacked this tar in `/usr/locale`, I enter the commands

```
sudo ./configure 
sudo make install
```

from within the `custom` directory.

However, instead of a clean install, I get the following errors (which I hope someone can help me out with):

```
nlykkei@nlykkei-Studio-XPS-1640:/usr/local/csv8.4/custom$ sudo make install
if [ yes = no ]; then if [ ! -f ./scheme ]; then /bin/rm -f ./scheme; ln -s ../bin/a6le/scheme ./scheme; fi; fi
if [ ! -f ./petite ]; then /bin/rm -f ./petite; ln -s ./scheme ./petite; fi
/bin/rm -f ./scheme
echo "const char *S_date_stamp = \"`date +%m%d%Y%H%M%S`\";" > datestamp.c
gcc -m64 -rdynamic -o ./scheme datestamp.c ../boot/a6le/kernel.o ../boot/a6le/custom.o   -lm -ldl -lncurses -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Mf-a6le:22: recipe for target 'scheme' failed
make[2]: *** [scheme] Error 1
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'buildpetite' failed
make[1]: *** [buildpetite] Error 2
Mf-install:64: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On recent versions of Ubuntu (and future versions of Debian e.g. "Buster", and other Debian based distros), you can install Chez Scheme directly from the repo(s) by:

```
sudo apt install chezscheme
```

Previously you had to install it by compiling from source. [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/) has been open source, for a few years now, and can be compiled from source, if it is not directly installable from the distribution's repo(s). Just [download the source code](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme) compile and install. This will install not just the "petite" runtime version but also the full compiler. You can compile and install the software with:

```
./configure
sudo make install
```

Full build and install instructions are available [here](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/master/BUILDING).

Pre-requisites for building are:

- GNU Make
- GCC
- Header files and libraries for ncurses
- Header files and libraries for X windows

Comment: Actually it's not currently working: `./installsh: 64: [: 0: unexpected operator` in the `sudo make install` step.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, install the `libncurses5-dev` package to get `libncurses.so`. (You can discover this by visiting http://packages.debian.org/file:libncurses.so (sadly, this doesn't seem to work for http://packages.ubuntu.com/file:libncurses.so).)

You may find other linkage errors if Chez requires other libraries to have development packages installed too. Use the same technique as above.

Comment: I also had to install X development libraries with:  `sudo apt install xorg-dev` (on 16.04)

Answer (score 2):

Go directly building from their Github.

[ChezScheme](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme)

And then just do

```
./configure
sudo make install
```

Prerequisites according to [Building](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/master/BUILDING) are:

- GNU Make
- gcc
- Header files and libraries for ncurses
- Header files and libraries for X windows

And yes in case On Ubuntu, install the **libncurses5-dev** as Chris stated. Did just that and have no errors shown in clean install.

Comment: I would also recommend to specify --installprefix=/usr/local/chezscheme to avoid mixing it with anything that might have already been installed to /usr/local.

Answer (score 1):

Chez Scheme has been open sourced since this question was asked.  Since Bionic (18.04LTS) the full chezscheme is available as a repository.

First do

```
sudo apt update
```

then install the package:

```
sudo apt install chezscheme
```

This provides both the `petite` interpreter and the full `scheme` compiler.

There is also a PPA for trusty and xenial here:

https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/lisp?field.series_filter=

Answer (score 0):

Download the RPM package instead and use alien from terminal to produce a deb file:

```
fakeroot alien PetiteChezScheme-8.4-1.x86_64.rpm
```

You may need to install `fakeroot`, `alien` for this to work:

```
apt-get install fakeroot alien
```

Then you'll have a deb file. If you are on a desktop you can just double click the file and it will open Software Center and you can click `install` and it will fix your dependency problems.